# Publish Installs with Facebook iOS SDK -> valid attribution ID or advertiser ID not found

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook iOS SDK (version 3.5) to publish installs for our mobile app so that we can track installs when we implement ads to drive installs. I'm running the following block of code in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:

```
[FBSettings publishInstall:OUR_APP_ID withHandler:^(FBGraphObject *response, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

This block of code logs the following to the console when launching the app on my iOS:

Response: (null)
Error: A valid attribution ID or advertiser ID was not found. Publishing install when neither of them is present is a no-op.

How can I resolve this error? I haven't been able to find any info on what an attribution ID or advertiser ID is, how to get one, or how to set up my app so that one can be found when publishing an install.

Answer (score 1):

The attribution ID is populated from data stored by the native Facebook application. Install the Facebook app, and login to an account, and the attribution id will be set.